# Html Page play video Streaming

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am streaming a video from VLC player on Http protocol on port 7777. I am not able to get the video playing in the web page. if i open vlc from android and enter my http stream url its playing the video.

Below is html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 


 <video width="700" src="http://192.168.31.100:7777" autoplay ></video>

</body> 
</html>
```

I have written a java code for listening UDP packets below is my java code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class RecieveUDP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(7777);
        byte[] receive = new byte[65535];
        DatagramPacket DpReceive = null;

        while (true) {

            // Step 2 : create a DatgramPacket to receive the data.
            DpReceive = new DatagramPacket(receive, receive.length);

            // Step 3 : revieve the data in byte buffer.
            ds.receive(DpReceive);

            System.out.println(receive.length);
            

            // Clear the buffer after every message.
            receive = new byte[65535];
        }
    }

}
```

This code i am running on my tomcat server.
When i am streaming on UDP port from Vlc i am getting packets but i am unable to play these streaming in my web page. Please suggest what should i show to play audio/video streaming in my webpage.

Comment: You have to write the stream into a blob and then create a URL from blob and then put it on the video tag,

Comment: What's blob how can I convert it to blob?

Comment: @blacksheep No, that isn't necessary

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui You will need to mux this video into something like WebM to be streamable.  You can't just forward whatever you're getting in via UDP.

Comment: @Brad thanks for your reply. I m using tomcat & i am doing streaming for the first time. so i didn't understand how can i  mux this video like WebM. Can you please provide sample code in java where i can pick this up

Comment: for beginner i would try only audio streaming first

Comment: If you output as FLV then you could use [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/), which uses Media Source Extensions (i.e. creates the blobs for you). Make sure you're outputting the right stream from VLC [this may help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Stream_to_a_website/#Method_2_H264_and_Flash_.flv)